# Play get instance of DatabaseConfigProvider

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm use Slick as a Play module. In this way, `DatabaseConfigProvider` will be injected to Controller.
In a special stage, I want get `DatabaseConfigProvider` out of Controller.
How can I get `DatabaseConfigProvider` instance?

Answer (score -1):

You can inject it like this:

```
class MyClass @Inject() (protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)
    extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[MyPostgresDriver]
```

With these imports:

```
import javax.inject.Inject
import database.MyPostgresDriver
import play.api.db.slick.{DatabaseConfigProvider, HasDatabaseConfigProvider}
import database.MyPostgresDriver.api._
```

Comment: hi, How can I get a `MyClass` instance and inject `DatabaseConfigProvider ` parameter?

Comment: MyClass is the name of your class, it was an example but there is nothing else to do. And to have a DatabaseConfigProvider instance, you juste have to import play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider